# String begins with a number return different result after query

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a table A like this:

```
+----+---------+--+
| Id |  Email  |  |
+----+---------+--+
|  1 | a@b.com |  |
|  2 | c@d.com |  |
|  3 | a@b.com |  |
|  4 | a@b.com |  |
|  5 | a@b.com |  |
+----+---------+--+
```

and my sql query is:

```
select Email
     , case when @record=Email 
            then @cnt:=@cnt+1 
            when @record:=Email 
            then @cnt:=1 
            end as n 
  from A
     , (select @cnt:=0, @record:='') r 
 order 
    by Id;
```

The purpose of this query is to find the consecutive number with same Email order by Id.

it will return

```
+---------+------+
| Email   | n    |
+---------+------+
| a@b.com | NULL |
| c@d.com | NULL |
| a@b.com | NULL |
| a@b.com |    1 |
| a@b.com |    2 |
+---------+------+
```

Why the n column has the null result, that's not what I expected.

But if I change the value of Email field in table A:

```
+------+----------+
| Id   | Email    |
+------+----------+
|    1 | 1a@b.com |
|    2 | 2c@d.com |
|    3 | 1a@b.com |
|    4 | 1a@b.com |
|    5 | 1a@b.com |
+------+----------+
```

it returns:

```
+----------+------+
| Email    | n    |
+----------+------+
| 1a@b.com |    1 |
| 2c@d.com |    1 |
| 1a@b.com |    1 |
| 1a@b.com |    2 |
| 1a@b.com |    3 |
+----------+------+
```

I think this is the right result, but why?

I am a little confused, can anyone help me?

Comment: You never declare the 'else'

Comment: What version of MySQL? And I agree with Strawberry, without `ELSE`, anything that doesn't match in the `CASE .. THEN` criteria will return `NULL`.

Comment: *But if I change the value of Email field in table A:* Test `0a@b.com` also...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `@record=Email` is false then the next alternative condition is investigated, `@record:=Email` assignement is performed, and assigned value is a value of an expression.

This expression is used as a condition, i.e. it has numeric context. Implicit datatype convertion is performed.

A string started from a letter gives zero value during this convertion. Which is treated as false.

CASE have no ELSE - so the output is NULL.

Answer (score 0):

This is a gaps and islands problem, and here is one approach using the difference in row numbers method:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) rn1,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Email ORDER BY Id) rn2
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT Id, Email, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Email, rn1-rn2 ORDER BY Id) AS cnt
FROM cte
ORDER BY Id;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

The general approach here is to generate a pseudo group for each "island" of like emails (based on the order provided by the `Id` column) by using the difference in row number as determined two different ways, combined with the email itself.  Then, we use `COUNT` as an analytic function to generate the count sequences for each effective email group.